# Store array of objects in AWS secret manager

Tags: arrays, json, amazon-web-services, aws-secrets-manager

I am trying to store array of objects in secret manager, but it always throws error when I click on "Key/Value" in secret manager, the error is `The secret value can't be converted to key name and value pairs.`.

The value I would like to store in secret manager is `"Users" : [{"username":"User1"},{"username":"User2"}]`

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can only store string values in Secret Manager. If you want to store an array you'll have to convert it to e.g. JSON string first.

Comment: I have converted the value as a JSON string, still issue persist. I have updated my Question.

Comment: I don't see any JSON strings in the question

Answer (score 3):

**Solution 1:**

If you want to save it as a **Plaintext**, try the following:

```json
{
  "Users": [
    {"username": "User1"},
    {"username": "User2"}
  ]
}
```

**Solution 2:**

If you want to save it as **key/value pairs**, use the following:

```json
{
    "username1": "User1",
    "username2": "User2"
}
```

**Solution 3:**

If you want to save it as **key/value pairs and don't want to change the format**, use the following:

```json
{
  "Users": "[{\"username\": \"User1\"},{\"username\": \"User2\"}]"
}
```

**Conclusion:**

You cannot convert a JSON object to a key/value pair if it is an array. You have to change the format as key/value pair is a list of key-with-value (e.g., `"key": "value"`) pairs. If you want it to be an array then store it as plaintext and retrieve it as a string and then convert it to JSON and use it accordingly. Or, you can have `Users` as key and the array as value which is a JSON string. Again, you need to retrieve it as a string and then convert it to JSON and use it accordingly but this time it is a key/value pair and not plaintext.

Comment: Arrays are not valid values in Secrets Manager.

Comment: They _are_ valid if stored as Plaintext.

Comment: @GuyIncognito They can be stored as Plaintext. I just tested it as well.

Comment: The question is about storing values in key/value pairs – now that the answer is edited I removed my downvote.

Answer (score 1):

Don't click **Key/Value**.

Instead, use **Plaintext** and extract the individual values in your program by converting the string to JSON (`json.loads()`) and referencing the individual elements.

For example:

```
object['Users'][0]['username']
```